# Caller not getting onaddstream event from callee

Tags: webrtc

I got some unexpected behavior while tinkering with WebRTC. I follow [the MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection) about RTCPeerConnection, and everything works fine, but when I comment out `caller.addStream(stream)` caller stops getting `onaddstream` event from callee.

Is that a bug or WebRTC is specified so?

Comment: what are your SDP constraints? Are you offering to receive and send media? Or just receive media?

Comment: Benjamin, yes caller was offering to receive media. Adding SDP constraints solved this problem. Thanks!